# Store and refresh object with EJB 2.0 and JPA (Toplink) problem

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, toplink

From my client app I want to call store and refresh in one EJB method instead of two calls to two methods. I made an EJB method, made it call the other two EJB methods and it looks simple, like this:

```
 public ZippedObjectWrapper saveAndRefresh(final Item p_item) {
    Long itemSavedId= save(p_item);
    return refresh(itemSavedId);
  }
```

The problem is Toplink which doesn't let me read the data and in the refresh part throws an exception:

Exception [TOPLINK-7123]
Exception Description: A successful writeChanges() has been called on this UnitOfWork.  As the commit process has been started but not yet finalized, the only supported operations now are commit, commitAndResume, release, any non-object level query or SQLCall execution.  The operation executeQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery) is not allowed at this time.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Changed method signatures.

Comment: Please use english variable names. This is impossible to read for the majority of the SO users.

Comment: How do you manage transactions?

Comment: How exactly do you mean?

Comment: Could you add the code for save and refresh methods?

Comment: The EJB methods don't do anything useful, they just call the Service layer. The Service layer methods do some reading/writing from the database. I could copy/paste it, but it's not that self-explanatory. Anything in particular I could check in the code/paste a part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Toplink, specifically the way it handles database operations in the version we're using. There is a partial solution when you extend a Toplink class, or better one, upgrade Toplink :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your save() method does, but I assume you are calling writeChanges() on your UnitOfWork.
Queries were not allow after writeChanges() in the version you are using.  Removing the writeChanges() should resolve the issue.

If you upgrade to EclipseLink and JPA, you can use flush() multiple times in a transaction and query after.  You could also maually use the RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork instead of the UnitOfWork to enable multiple calls to writeChanges() and allow querying.